# Asterisk : automatically answer call after originate

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I have an asterisk 1.8.13 running quite well, and thanks to stackoverflow's questions, I am now able to originate a call via AMI.
When the call is originated, the SIP phone is ringing, and when I manually answer, it calls the extension.

I REALLY would like to do the same thing but without the need to answer myself on the SIP phone. (Not only a 'Async: yes' that would call the extension at the same time)

The goal is that when I send a command to AMI, my SIP phone is automatically answered and the extension called, no need to touch the phone physically.

I already checked :

> [Originate a call with Asterisk - without the originating extension ringing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360899/originate-a-call-with-asterisk-without-the-originating-extension-ringing)
>
> [Asterisk AMI - pickup call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836466/asterisk-ami-pickup-call)

But both do not work on my configuration (maybe due to me obviously).

Here my extensions.conf :

```
(...)
[globalcontext](!)
include => parkedcalls
exten => _X.,1,AGI(agi:async)

exten => _1XX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN},20,tT)
exten => _1XX,2,VoiceMail(${EXTEN}@test)

[nol](globalcontext)
exten => _0XXXXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/to-ovh/${EXTEN})
(...)
```

Here is my sip.conf :

```
[template](!)
type=friend
host=dynamic
dtmfmode=rfc2833
disallow=all
allow=ulaw

[102](template)
fullname = John Doe
defaultuser = john
secret = sippass
context = nol
```

Here is my **working** AMI session for originating call from SIP phone 102 to ext 0101010101:

```
Action: Login
Username: admin
Secret: mypassword

Action: Originate
Channel: SIP/102
Context: nol
Exten: 0101010101
Priority: 1
Callerid: 0101010101
Timeout: 15000
ActionID: b4646a6465e546f
```

I hope it will be clear enough.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Thanks to arheops' answers**, I finally found the solution for my Cisco SPA525G2 & 504G SIP phones, via AMI telnet connection.
I just had to add the header via a variable to tell the phones to auto-answer :

```
Action: Originate
Channel: SIP/102
Context: nol
Exten: 0101010101
Priority: 1
Variable: __SIPADDHEADER51=Call-Info: <sip:192.168.0.10>\;answer-after=0
Callerid: 0101010101
Timeout: 15000
ActionID: b4646a6465e546f
```

Where 192.168.0.10 is the IP of my asterisk server.

References are :

- http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+SipAddHeader
- http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Page
- those from **arheops**.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

That depend of you phone. Most phones have auto-answer button

Also you can set some headers to force phone intercom or auto-answer feature.

For example this page about Polycom phone

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Polycom+auto-answer+config

General info about intercom http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Paging+and+Intercom

Comment: Hello, SIP phones are Cisco SPA525G2 and SPA504, there is only 'auto answer page' on the phone conf, which does not apply. I will try the other way with headers ...

Comment: You can have 2 extension per phone. One without autoanswer one with(line 2). Headers also work fine with cisco phones