# Asterisk IP-PBX: API to set up and tear down a call between two extensions

Tags: asterisk, pbx, asteriskami

I have a working system that controls a Cisco CUCM IP-PBX to set up and tear down a call between two parties A and B; it makes use of Java's JTAPI to:

1. make A call B
2. make B answer (pick up)
3. (wait for a few seconds)
4. make either A or B drop the call

Now I want to do the same with an Asterisk PBX (version 13.17.0). From what I have gathered, [Asterisks JTAPI implementation](http://asterisk-jtapi.sourceforge.net/) doesn't work for recent Asterisks; the latest version that I can find, dates from 2006 and it seems to try and send AMI commands to which Asterisk replies something along the lines of "no such command" - I'm guessing the AMI syntax has changed over the years.

What I'm using now is a library called [asterisk-java](http://asterisk-java.org/) and more specifically, its AMI support. I'm sending an `OriginateAction` and the net effect is that:

1. Asterisk calls A
2. I have to pick up A's phone manually
3. A calls B
4. I have to pick up B's phone manually
5. finally a call is established between A and B

So instead of a fully automated process like in the Cisco case, I have to do manual work and I can't seem to find an API to just set up a call between A and B and having it drop after a couple of seconds.

**Questions**: is the AMI the correct API for my use case or is there a better alternative? And what API calls do I have to make to establish and drop a call?

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score -1):

Does this answered question help with establishing a call without picking up:

[Originate a call with Asterisk - without the originating extension ringing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360899/originate-a-call-with-asterisk-without-the-originating-extension-ringing)

To have a channel drop a call, using AMI, you can use 'BridgeKick' to boot a channel, or 'BridgeDestroy' to cause each channel to 'BridgeLeave':
https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+ManagerAction_BridgeKick